How to detect end of @Async method in Spring Boot and run some code
I'm writing a Spring Boot app that I want to run some multi-threaded calculations in background. At one time there can be from just a few up to several thousand calculations in queue so I don't want to rely solely on ThreadPoolTaskExecutors queueCapacity. What is the best way to tackle this problem.
I thought about calling calculate method recursively at the end but as far as I know it is not good idea (correct me if I'm wrong).
This is how my app looks like now:
AsyncConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {

    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("taskExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}

CalculationContext.java
import lombok.extern.java.Log;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

@Log
@Component
public class CalculationContext {

    private final SettingsContext         settingsContext;
    private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  taskExecutor;
    private final CompletionService<Void> completionService;

    private final BlockingQueue<CalculationData> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public CalculationContext(
            SettingsContext settingsContext,
            @Qualifier("taskExecutor") ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor
    ) {
        this.settingsContext   = settingsContext;
        this.taskExecutor      = taskExecutor;
        this.completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(taskExecutor);
    }

    public void addToQueue(CalculationData data) {
        queue.add(data);
        startScraping();
    }

    public void startCalculation() {
        if (queue.isEmpty()) return;
        if (getAvailableThreads() == 0) return;

        do {
            try {
                CalculationData data = queue.take();
                scrapePage(data);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } while (getAvailableThreads() > 0);


    }

    @Async
    public void calculate(CalculationData data) {
        //This is where all logic will be
    }

    private int getAvailableThreads() {
        return taskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize() - taskExecutor.getActiveCount();
    }
}


Async methods are mostly fire-and-forget. You call it but you don't know when it's executed, or when it's finished.
Fortunately, Creating Asynchronous Methods shows how to do it in its GitHubLookupService  class - return a CompletableFuture<Void> instead of Void:
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Void> calculate(CalculationData data) {
    //This is where all logic will be
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}

Now you can define what to do next when you call it:
calculationContext.calculate(data)
        .thenRun(() -> {
             //This code is called after calculate finishes
        });


How about adding before/after aspect? I am not sure will that work?

That would probably work, but only if the before/after part would always be the same. With CompletableFuture you can add different code before (just by adding it before the method call) and after (by using thenRun), depending on where the method is called.
